# Isometry on $\Bbb{R^n}$ which is not orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

I have seen in wikipedia that the orthogonal matrices on $\Bbb{R^n}$, denoted by $O(n)=\{x\in GL_n(\Bbb{R}): x^tx=I\} $ is a subgroup of $E(n)$- the group of isometries.
I am a little bit confused because untill now I used the definition isometry in $C^*$ algebras. There, if we have an isometry acting on $\Bbb{C^n}$ it's autumatically invertible (because $\Bbb{C^n}$ is finite dimensional) thus unitary. 
So, first- why the same argument with $\Bbb{R^n}$ is finite dimensional and thus invertible from the right implies invertible, does not imply just $O(n)=\{x\in M_n(\Bbb{R}): x^tx=I\}$?
Actually I know this is true but the explanations I saw are complicated and the argument "$\Bbb{R^n}$ finite dimensional" is not used.

Second, I don't understand why $O(n)$ does not equal $E(n)$. Can you give an example of isometry which is not in $O(n)$? Why in $C^*$ algebras the definitions coincide?

Thank you!

Comment: Translation is an isometry which cannot be written as a transformation by an $n$ by $n$ matrix.

Comment: $E(n) = O(n) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$, so an isometry $(D,d)$ consists of an orthogonal matrix $D$ and a translation part $d$. Applying $(D,d)$ to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ gives us $Dx+d$, and the group operation on $E(n)$ is defined as $(D_1,d_1)(D_2,d_2) = (D_1D_2, D_1d_2 + d_1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about $C^*-$ algebras, but $O(n)$ does not consider translation of $\Bbb R^n$, since these are not linear transformation.

For instance: $ v\longmapsto v+w$ where $w$ is a fixed vector in $\Bbb R^n$ is an isometry.

Comment: The same is true in $C^*$ algebra, or in fact, any normed space: translations are isometries trivially by the way metric is defined by the norm.

Comment: I see. This solves me the problem. I didn't know we consider also non-lineae transformations. Thank you!